# Import SQL to SQL DB: How can I populate columns that exist in destination, not source?

Tags: sql, ssis, mapping

I'm using SSIS to import data from one DB to another existing DB. Some columns in the destination tables do not exist in the source tables. Seems the Import & Export Wizard only allows me to select unmapped columns from the source and match them with these new columns in the destination. I'd like to be able to just provide one piece of data to import into all rows of these new columns.
Would like to use the GUI if possible because I'm not skilled at writing scripts. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In SSIS, you can add a "derived column" component that will add columns to the buffer rows with the value you want (either a string or an expression).

Comment: Played around with this a little but it looks like this is where I'd add columns to the destination. The columns already exist in the destination (but not in the source). So under the 'Derived column' header, I wouldn't select 'add as new column' right? But the only other options under that header are columns in the source, no the destination...

Comment: Let's say you have a source and a destination component. Right after the source, you add a "derived column" in which you add a new column. This will add a new colum to your source input, available to be mapped on the destination column.

Comment: you are adding columns to the buffer not the destination.  As @DominicGoulet states, having added this to the buffer, it is available to be mapped to the destination column you need it to.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible in the GUI.  However, it would be a simple script after the data is loaded with SSIS:

```
UPDATE table SET newcolumn = new value
```

If you need to filter the rows, just add

```
WHERE column = value ...
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem with that is that the import errors-out if I'm not inserting anything into those columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could change your source to a select query and list out the columns along with the static value you want to map.

```
SELECT SOURCECOLUMN_1,SOURCECOLUMN_2,....,SOURCECOLUMN_N,'VALUE' AS DESTINATIONCOLUMN FROM Source_Table
```

My original thought was that you could use the query right in the Import & Export wizard. you can obviously do alot more if you go in and edit the package, but it sounded like you didn't have much expereince with that. Here is how you would do this in the wizard.

After you have selected your source and destination databases you can Specify Table Copy or Query. Select the **Write a query to specify the data to transfer** option
[image: Specify Table Copy or Query]

On the next screen enter the query listing out all of the columns and add in your static columns.
[image: Queryscreen]

On the Next screen You will need to select the Destination table or it will default to creating a new table named *Query*. You should be able to choose from the drop down. As long as you aliased your extra columns with the same names it should map correctly. You can go in and edit mappings here if needed.
[image: Destination]

You can then save off the SSIS package and it will source form the query.

Alternatively if you already have the SSIS pacakge created without the extra columns you can go in to the Data Flow and change the **Data access mode** in the OLE DB Source to be a SQL Command instead of a table or view. Add your query here.

[image]

You can then go into the properties of the OLE DB Desitination in the Dataflow and map the new column. You could also add in a derived column as @DominicGoulet by adding in a Dervied Column task and putting your static information here and then mapping. If you want to see that solution too let me know.

Comment: That sounds perfect. Can you give me step-by-step how to set-up my package? Sorry, very new to SSIS. Like what are my 'Control Flow' items and what are my 'Data Flow' items and where do I add the select statement you suggest? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: +1. This example works using only the Data Import/Export feature of SQL Management Studio